# What is so great about 7?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, divisibility

I'm going to write down my problem verbatim:

> Write down the integers from $1$ to $50$ in rows of $10$ numbers each.
>   Mark out $1$, and then cross out all multiples of $2$ greater than $2$
>   (i.e., cross out, $4, 6, 8, . . . ). 3$ is not crossed out, so cross
>   out all multiples of $3$ greater than $3$ (i.e., cross out $6, 9, 12, . . . )$. 
>   Find the next number $f$ after $3$ which is not crossed out.
>   This is the next prime. Cross out all non-unary multiples of $f$.
>   Continue in this way until you get to the end of the list, and the
>   numbers which haven’t been crossed out are the primes less than $50$.
>   Notice that the last sequence of multiples you crossed off while doing
>   this were multiples of $7$.
>
> What’s special about $7$ in this list?
>
> If, instead of using just the numbers from $1$ to $50$ you had used
>   the numbers from $1$ to $1000$, what’s the smallest composite number
>   that would not have been crossed off after crossing off the multiples
>   of $7$?

Comment: Which multiple of $7$ was the last (only) one you erased? Is that a coincidence?

Comment: Well, 7,8,9. So it's pretty great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is known that a composite integer $a$ has a prime divisor $p$ that satisfies the inequality $p\leq a$. If you let $a=50$, then it will have prime divisor $p$ that is less than or equal to $\sqrt{50}$.The greatest among possible p's is 7. Thus in employing the Sieve you will just cross out the multiples of prime $p$ 2,3,5 and lastly multiples of 7. The numbers that are not cross out are the primes from 1 to 50 which are 2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29,31,37,41,43 and 47. The special in 7 is that it is the greatest prime that you need to cross out its multiple.

Comment: Thanks, and is 121 correct for the second part of the question. If so, what is the reasoining behind it.

Comment: Do you know what non-unary means?

Comment: Where have you heard of that word? And to answer your question 121 is correct.

Comment: In the question it says "Cross out all non-unary multiples of f"

Comment: for the explanation that 121, I agree with Scott

Comment: Sorry for the non-unary word but im not familiar with it.

Answer (score 4):

$7$ is the largest integer less than the square root of $50$.

Comment: What does non-unary multiples of f mean

Comment: Why didn't you start out by asking what the terms mean? - I'm not a native english speaker, and I don't remember having seen the word "non-unary" before, but knowing Eratosthenes' sieve, I'm pretty sure it just means that the other factor has to be greater than 1.

Comment: Okay and what would happen if, instead of using just the numbers from 1 to 50 I use the numbers from 1 to 1000. What would be the smallest composite number that would not have been crossed off after crossing off the multiples of 7?

Comment: It has nothing to do with $7$. When finding primes from $2$ to $N$, you only go up to $\sqrt{N}$.

Comment: @Eff Okay, I get that. But, what is the answer to my second question?

Comment: @variancemaster My guess would be $121$. $11$ is the next prime after $7$, so I think $11\times 11 = 121$ is the smallest composite not expressible as a multiple of some prime less than or equal to $7$.

Answer (score 1):

First, write down each number like you told me to do:

$\begin{array}{cccccccccc}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10\\
11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 & 16 & 17 & 18 & 19 & 20\\
21 & 22 & 23 & 24 & 25 & 26 & 27 & 28 & 29 & 30\\
31 & 32 & 33 & 34 & 35 & 36 & 37 & 38 & 39 & 40\\
41 & 42 & 43 & 44 & 45 & 46 & 47 & 48 & 49 & 50
\end{array}$

Now cross out $1$ and multiples of $2$ greater than $2$:

$\begin{array}{cccccccccc}
\not1 & 2 & 3 & \not4 & 5 & \not6 & 7 & \not8 & 9 & \not10\\
11 & \not12 & 13 & \not14 & 15 & \not16 & 17 & \not18 & 19 & \not20\\
21 & \not22 & 23 & \not24 & 25 & \not26 & 27 & \not28 & 29 & \not30\\
31 & \not32 & 33 & \not34 & 35 & \not36 & 37 & \not38 & 39 & \not40\\
41 & \not42 & 43 & \not44 & 45 & \not46 & 47 & \not48 & 49 & \not50
\end{array}$

Now cross out multiples of $3$ greater than $3$:

$\begin{array}{cccccccccc}
\not1 & 2 & 3 & \not4 & 5 & \not6 & 7 & \not8 & \not9 & \not10\\
11 & \not12 & 13 & \not14 & \not15 & \not16 & 17 & \not18 & 19 & \not20\\
\not21 & \not22 & 23 & \not24 & 25 & \not26 & \not27 & \not28 & 29 & \not30\\
31 & \not32 & \not33 & \not34 & 35 & \not36 & 37 & \not38 & \not39 & \not40\\
41 & \not42 & 43 & \not44 & \not45 & \not46 & 47 & \not48 & 49 & \not50
\end{array}$

The next not-crossed out number is $5$, which is then $f$.  Cross out all the non-unary numbers of that:

$\begin{array}{cccccccccc}
\not1 & 2 & 3 & \not4 & 5 & \not6 & 7 & \not8 & \not9 & \not10\\
11 & \not12 & 13 & \not14 & \not15 & \not16 & 17 & \not18 & 19 & \not20\\
\not21 & \not22 & 23 & \not24 & \not25 & \not26 & \not27 & \not28 & 29 & \not30\\
31 & \not32 & \not33 & \not34 & \not35 & \not36 & 37 & \not38 & \not39 & \not40\\
41 & \not42 & 43 & \not44 & \not45 & \not46 & 47 & \not48 & 49 & \not50
\end{array}$

As you just saw, $49$ is not crossed out, so that's the smallest composite number of the group that hasn't been crossed out, plus it's $7^2$.

Comment: ReliableMathBoy: I've tried to improve alignment in your post. (Feel free to revert the edit, if you don't like the new version.) You can find more about using tables/arrays in some post on meta. For example [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6734/how-can-i-put-a-table-here) or [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4240/how-do-i-insert-a-table-when-asking-a-question) and in other posts shown there among linked questions.

Comment: Well, at least there's a great job of aligning :)